# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

Tags: wordpress, ajaxform

I having issue with ajax submit form in wordpress, here's my code:

**AJAX**:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: formData,
      })
      .success(function( response ) {
        if( response.success ) {
          console.log(response);
        } else {
          console.log('Error: ' + response.data);
        }
      })
      .error(function( xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError ) {
        console.log('Request failed: ' + thrownError.message);
      });
```

**PHP** (functions.php):

```
add_action ('wp_ajax_call_store_voting', 'store_voting') ;
add_action ('wp_ajax_nopriv_store_voting', 'store_voting') ;

function store_voting () {

    $return_value = 'Successful!';

    echo json_encode($return_value);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Could you format your code, please?

Comment: The error is suggesting that your ajax call is not returning valid json as a response. The error is saying the first character of the response is `<` (probably an HTML tag) which is not a valid token to start a json response. You can inspect the body of the response in a browser. For example in chrome, view the network panel and look through the XHR requests. This should tell you the contents of the response and help with troubleshooting.

Comment: @AndrewChart so i should look under the Headers section in XHR?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ajax, so can anyone guide me through?

Comment: Now i'm having 

wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Hi @SteveKhong - so in Chrome devtools, look at the network tab and filter by XHR, then fire the request. You should see the request "happen" in the network panel, and when you click it you can see lots of information about the request, response, cookies and timing This is what it looks like. This screenshot shows the response body for an AJAX call that returns json output. If your server is returning something other than json for some reason - this is where you can see it in the browser: https://imgur.com/z1hcguV